# Polymer how to change Toolbar text size on scroll

Tags: css, polymer, android-toolbar

I am using the Polymer for my site with the header panel flex mode set to "Waterfall Tall". I would like to achieve an effect similar to this :

https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/icons.html

That is, the text is large when the user is at the top of the the page and becomes small on scrolling. 
How do I achieve this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found a relatively easy way to do this. It involves using a  given here 
https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-scroll-header-panel

Answer (score 0):

Add to :host ::content header h1

```
:host ::content header h1 {
  -webkit-transform: none !important;
  transform: none !important;
}
```

or add to:

```
h1 {
      -webkit-transform: none !important;
      transform: none !important;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. This doesn't change the text size or for that matter even collapse the header on scrolling.